# Codeigniter: No Tables Used

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I've a table of users. Which data is lot of duplicate data. I want to keep all those duplicate data. So I've 3 conditions

1. Account with no picture
2. Account with picture
3. Duplicate account with picture or no picture

For example

ID | Email | Picture
1  | ba@mail.com | img.jpg
2  | ba@mail.com | *NULL*
3  | ba@mail.com | img2.jpg
4  | ba@mail.com | *NULL*
5  | aa@mail.com | *NULL*

So how to get the ID of those duplicate account, but prioritizing picture is not null, and prioritizing the latest ID? (I want it returns '3')

Here I Try the code

```
$this->db->select('id');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $query0 = $this->db->get();

        if($query0->num_rows() == 1){
            return $query0->row('id');
        } else {
            $this->db->select('id');
            $this->db->from('users');
            $this->db->where(array('email' => $email, 'picture IS NOT' => NULL));
            $query1 = $this->db->get();
            if($query1->num_rows() == 1){
                return $query1->row('id');
            } else {
                $this->db->select('id');
                $this->db->from('users');
                $this->db->where('email', $email);
                $this->db->limit('1');

                return $this->db->get()->row('id');
            }
```

It works well if account duplicate, and both of them with NULL on picture column. But it doesn't work well when the account doesn't duplicate OR duplicate but one of them have a picture not null.

Here the error code:
Error Number: 1096
No tables used

Thank you!

Comment: At some point in the future you're going to kick yourself for designing that way. `select max(id) from users where picture is not null and email = 'email'`

Comment: just updating my table in question @Kisaragi

Comment: that's a weird schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally just done with some messy n tricky code

```
$this->db->select_max('id');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where(array('email' => $email, 'picture IS NOT NULL' => NULL));
        if($this->db->get()->row('id') >= 1){
            $this->db->select_max('id');
            $this->db->from('users');
            $this->db->where(array('email' => $email, 'picture IS NOT NULL' => NULL));
            return $this->db->get()->row('id');
        } else {
            $this->db->select_max('id');
            $this->db->from('users');
            $this->db->where('email',$email);
            return $this->db->get()->row('id');
        }
```

This just works very well. Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 1):

This may heplful to you

```
//in below query $emil is your input taht you need to find duplicate
$q=$this->db->query("SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM users WHERE picture IS NOT NULL AND email = '$email');
$id=$q->row()->id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably move pictures to another table and use user.id as a foreign key there. Anyhow this sounds like what you want:

```
    $this->db->select('max(id)');
    $this->db->where('(email = "$email" and picture is not null) or email = "$email"');
    $result = $this->db->get('users')->row();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using these 3 conditions and let me know if it works.

$this->db->select(GROUP_CONCAT(id), email, GROUP_CONCAT(picture));

$this->db->group_by('email');

$this->db->order_by('picture','DESC');